# XPath to return a array of string concatenation of multiples child node values

Tags: xml, xpath, string-concatenation

If I have the below XML

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>2</p> 3 
</div>
<div>
    <p>4</p> 5 <p>6</p>
</div>
```

How to specify a xpath to return a array of strings like this:

```
{ 1, 2, 46 }
```

All attempts I did returned the following result:

```
{ 1, 2, 4, 6}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are

```
concat(string-join(//div[count(p) = 1]/p, ',') , ',' , string-join(//div[count(p) &gt; 1]/string-join(p, ''), ','))
```

will return 1,2,46

As you will need to concatenate some p tags under the same div tag so in all the cases this will result string which can be converted to array by tokenise() function.

Here's the trick:

**First part**

```
string-join(//div[count(p) = 1]/p, ',')
```

This will only select the div which have only one p tag .. so no concatenation required here. this will get

```
1,2
```

**Second Part**
string-join(//div[count(p) > 1]/string-join(p, ''), ',')

This part concat all the p tags under the same div, then join all of the dev that has more than one p chid tag.

this part will get

```
46
```

***Example:***

```
<div>
    <p>1</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>2</p> 3 
</div>
<div>
    <p>4</p> 5 <p>6</p>
</div>
<div>1<p>2</p>3 , 1<p>2</p><p>3</p>4</div>
```

The output will be

```
1,2,46,223
```

If you want it as array you can tokenize it.

```
tokenize(concat(string-join(//div[count(p) = 1]/p, ',') , ',' , string-join(//div[count(p) &gt; 1]/string-join(p, ''), ',')) , ',')
```

I hope this could help.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry it was not so clear, but what I wrote was just an example. 
I have hundreds of tags <div> and <p> tags appear in several forms like:

1<p>2</p>3 ,  1<p>2</p><p>3</p>4 etc...

Comment: Also, when I said the format, such as {1,2,3 etc} I meant the own contents of the array, not a string in the array format.
Note: I am using lxml from Python.

Comment: I solved with a "for" loop for each node, but your thinking helped me to find this solution. Probably your should work too. Thank you!