# Get Xpath to the parts of the node

Tags: arrays, xml, xpath

I'm new with XPath so sorry if it's a silly question for you. 
I need to extract just a price without "$" from the first span class="price"

```
<span class="price">
    <span class="sup">$</span>
    1
    <span class="currency-delimiter">.</span>
    <span class="sup">23</span>
</span>
<span class="price">
    <span class="sup">$</span>
    4
    <span class="currency-delimiter">.</span>
    <span class="sup">56</span>
</span>
<span class="price">
    <span class="sup">$</span>
    7
    <span class="currency-delimiter">.</span>
    <span class="sup">89</span>
</span>
```

Xpath that I came with is

> //span[@class='price'])[1]

But it gives me an array of each element [$][1][.][23]
And I need just 1.23 without "$". Could you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Like using google maybe?

Comment: No! what is google?!

Comment: What is the 1, 4, and 7 in your example? They are outside xml tags. Also is that the complete xml? It has no root element.

Comment: you could try `substring-after(//span[@class='price'], '$')`, but it will include whitespace between the numbers because there is whitespace in the original document

Comment: erik, 1, 4, 7 - these are dollar amount of the price. There are 3 prices in this example $1.23, $4.56 and $7.89. So I need just first one without "$". I do not put root as I mention "//span[@class='price'])[1]" works fine but it gives array.

Comment: Keith Hall, I played with a "substring-after" but it works for strings. In my example I have an array. So I need to concatenate it first to use "substring-after".

Comment: I think my answer should be somewhere [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650555/xpath-to-return-a-array-of-string-concatenation-of-multiples-child-node-values) and "substring-after". I will let you know if I get it first

Comment: `substring-after` flattens the array of nodes into the text they contain, because an implicit `string` function is run automatically. Try it :)

Comment: @Keith Hall, You right!!!! it works! Thanks! And for some reason I do not need to mention first elemet - it automatically pick up just first span with class="price"!  How can tag your comment as an answer? I am new here.. )

Comment: @YevgenKo, it's common in such situations to ask that Keith submit his comment(s) as an answer for you to accept.

Comment: @KeithHall, please submit your comment as an answer for me to accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, you can use the `string` function on a node to get all the text inside it. e.g. `string(//span[@class='price'][1])`  (And if you use it on a nodeset, a.k.a. an array of nodes, it will automatically apply only to the first node. [See the official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string) for more details.)

Note that this will include all whitespace (i.e. `'\n    $\n    1\n    .\n    23\n'` where `\n` represents a newline, so you may want to use the [`normalize-space` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) to remove the leading whitespace and replace each other instance of whitespace with a single space character, which will make the result more like `$ 1 . 23`.

Now, to remove the `$` character from the beginning, I would suggest to use the [`substring-after` function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-after), as it therefore won't matter whether or not you use the aforementioned `normalize-space` function, like this: `substring-after(normalize-space(string(//span[@class='price'])), '$')`

Now, it's worth noting that `substring-after` (and `normalize-space`) will implicitly call the `string` function, so you can safely omit this and just use `substring-after(normalize-space(//span[@class='price']), '$ ')`.  In this example, I have changed the second argument to `substring-after` to `$`, so that the space after the `$` will also be removed.